# even if editor said they are prepared to accept the manuscript. but still possible to be rejected?

Tags: publications

I submitted my manuscript this July and got comments from two reviewers and two editors. It seems like there was one reviewer no in favor of my manuscript although s/he did not directly say to reject my manuscript though. The other one was positive and said to accept mine with a minor revision. Overall, editors told me in the email that they are prepared to accept my paper. BUT it will be SUBJECT to how I revise the original manuscript. So since then, I have been revising the manuscript and responding to every single question that editors and reviewers raised.
I am trying to be meticulous and working on revising the manuscript thoroughly.
However, I don't want to get my hopes up. It's kind of self-defense mentality I guess.
According to the editors' comment, are there high chances that my manuscript will be accepted as long as I do my job decently? or I don't know, this is my first time to try to get a paper published, I have any idea on this. Is there still possibility of being rejected even if the revision is not so bad?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying too hard to parse what the editor is saying because you think that an editor is some kind of black box that operates on its own rules. But in reality, an editor is just a person like you and I, and if that person says something in plain language, it's a reasonable approach to believe that what they say is actually what they mean. That is, if you got a reply that states...

> that they are prepared to accept my paper. BUT it will be SUBJECT to how I revise the original manuscript

then that is exactly what you should assume: If you do a reasonably good job at revising the manuscript, then the editor will accept the paper. There is really not more to it than what it actually says -- read it as if your room mate said it.

Comment: Probably, I was trying too hard to understand what the editors said. But getting a paper published is very important and pretty hard in my field, which is why I am obsessed over tiny little things.. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to still be rejected, but you are doing the right thing to make it less likely. "It ain't over 'til it's over" as Yogi Berra once said.

You are probably in good shape. Get a colleague to review your updates, perhaps for some advice on the overall product.

Comment: I will definitely hire(?) or ask someone to go over my revised manuscript. I am working on all cylinders so if it will be rejected, I am too depressed and frustrated. I hope that does not happen though. Thank you for your comment!